# Can i get output 3 if no. is 2 and vice versa in php without using if,while or ternary operators?

Tags: php

If my input is 2 output should be 3.
If input is 3 then output should be 2.

We can't use if else or any ternary operator.

We can't use: `if($n == 2) { echo 2; }`

Comment: _we can't use if else or any ternary operator._ - Why? What is expected output when input is 5? Or 17? Or you have just these two possible values?

Comment: what about switch statement ???

Comment: twenty one days remaining for April 1st....... pls wait...

Comment: without any condition statement , not seems to possible

Comment: we just have two input option 2 or 3 @panther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$output=4;
do {
$output--;
$n--;
}while ($n>=2);
echo $output;
```

Or short one using mod:

```
echo (3 % $n) + 2;
```